# JS backspace keypress event triggered sometimes, sometimes not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code :

```
container.unbind('keypress').bind('keypress',function (e) {

            var code = e.which,
                charac = String.fromCharCode(code),
                totalChar = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ''),
                diff,
                previousChar = publisher.typeHistory.length > 0 ? publisher.typeHistory[publisher.typeHistory.length-1]:''
                previousCharCode = previousChar.charCodeAt(0);

            if(e.keyCode === undefined){ // backspace
                getCharacterDiff();
                console.log(totalChar.length-1);
                if(totalChar.length-1 === 0){
                    publisher.typeHistory = [];
                }
            }  

            console.log(previousChar);
            if(isCharacterKeyPress(code)){
                if (charac.toUpperCase() != charac.toLowerCase() ) { // Is a char or space


                    if(charac === charac.toUpperCase()){ // Is a char upper ?

                        if(previousChar === ' '){
                            console.log('upper + previous == space ', publisher.typeHistory);
                        }else {
                            publisher.typeHistory = [];
                        }

                        push = true;
                    }
                    else if (charac === charac.toLowerCase()){
                        if(previousCharCode === 32){
                            publisher.typeHistory = [];

                        }
                        if(hasUpperCase(publisher.typeHistory.join(''))){
                            push = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            push = false;
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        push = false;
                    }


                }
                else if (code === 32){
                    console.log('space');
                    console.log(previousCharCode);
                    if (previousCharCode === 32){
                        push = false;
                        publisher.typeHistory = [];
                    }

                    // else if(previousChar === 32) { // is the spacebar ?
                    //  console.log(previousChar);

                    // }
                }
                else { // = it's a number / , / ., etc..
                        console.log('not chara or space');
                        push = false;
                        publisher.typeHistory = [];



                }


                if (push) {
                    publisher.typeHistory.push(charac);
                }

            }

            console.log(publisher.typeHistory);
            previousTotal = publisher.typeHistory.join('');


            if (publisher.typeHistory.length > 2) {
                exp = publisher.typeHistory.join('');
                publisher.getResults(service,type,exp);
            }
            else {
                if(publisher.typeHistory.length === 0){
                    publisher.typeHistory = [];

                }
                publisher.hideResults();
            }

    });
```

With this, I handle which keys are typed in elements that have `contenteditable=true`, then I send it to a method that makes a request to a PHP script.

Here, `container` can be any element with contenteditable=true.

The problem is : I use `e.keyCode === undefined` to check if the user type backspace, so I can update the request. But `e.keyCode === undefined` only works on a single element, not the others (on the other the keypress event is not triggered).

So I don't know where this comes from :

- I know keypress event can't detect backspace key press (but well, in this case, with this code, it does)
- There's no difference in HTML / JS between anay elements that can be `container`
- I can't use keyup / keydown, as it's not case sensitive

What do I miss ?

Comment: *I know keypress event shouldn't be triggered on backspace key.* Do you have sources backing that claim?

Comment: Well, what I said is pretty confusing : what I mean is 'keypress event is not called when pressing backspace key'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MDN on the [keypress event:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

> The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key
>   normally produces a character value

So you have to use `keyup` or `keydown` events for certain keys, such as escape or backspace, because they don't produce characters.

The keycode for backspace is `8`, so your code could look like follows:

```
container.unbind('keyup').bind('keyup',function (e) {

    ...

    if(e.keyCode === 8){ // backspace
        getCharacterDiff();
        console.log(totalChar.length-1);
        if(totalChar.length-1 === 0){
            publisher.typeHistory = [];
        }
    }  

    ...

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that did the job. Nevertheless, I had to use another event 'DOMSubtreeModified', that fit more to my needs.